# Python/PHPSerialize TypeError: 'method' object does not support item assignment

Tags: php, python, serialization

I want to set a value in Python 3. It is unserialized via PHPSerialize and I believe it's a dictionary, but I have encountered an error:

```
TypeError: 'method' object does not support item assignment.
```

My code:

```
def setValue(self, p, set):
    a = self.getData()
    a[p] = set
    return self.updateData(a)

def getData (self):
    self.mysql.execute('SELECT data FROM users WHERE id='+str(self.id))
    result=self.mysql.fetchone()
    return phpserialize.loads(result[0])
```

Help?

Answer (score 0):

Could you print out the result of `isinstance(result, dict)`?  This will check whether or not 'method' is really a dictionary object.  It could very well have been initialized as something immutable.  Although I am unsure where this 'method' object was initialized, it may be helpful to use `results = copy.deepcopy(dictionary_object_here)` in order to preserve the structure of the dictionary.  Additional information regarding the class that 'self' refers to would be helpful